# Is there a way to convert from a string to a list in SASS?

Tags: sass

I have a mixin that takes a varying sized list of args, and I want to make it impossible to call it incorrectly :)

```
@include foo(1, 2, 3);
@include foo(1 2 3);
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to convert `'1 2 3'` into `(1 2 3)`

Comment: Your second example is not a string, it is still a list.  Sass allows lists to be delimited with either spaces or commas.

Comment: @cimmanon -- Yeah, I realized that, thanks :)  Answered my own question below.  Think it's the best way?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that your question is misleading to future visitors because you aren't trying to convert a string to a list.